# Excel function that returns difference between month?

Tags: excel, vba, function

I have a worksheet that has a start date and end date. I need to get the number of months between these dates. I used the formula `=MONTH(B1)-MONTH(A1)` to get that #. However this formula fails when my dates span multiple years - if start date is 1/1/2014 and end date is 1/1/2015, then it returns a "1", when I'd like to get a "12".

I then tried `DATEDIF(A1,B1,"m")` to get the # of months between the dates, and that worked. My issue, however, can be summarized by the following example:

### Situation 1:

> Start Date: 1/5/2014
>
> End Date:   3/1/2014
>
> "MonthDif": **2**
>
> DateDif: **1**

### Situation 2:

> Start Date: 1/5/2014
>
> End Date:   3/10/2014
>
> "MonthDif": **2**
>
> DateDif: **2**

As you can see, the `DATEDIF` function returns the # of *complete* months, while my `month - month` function returns the number of months "occupied" by the difference between the start and end dates, regardless if they are complete months.

I need the number of months, regardless if full months, over any date period! Basically, I need exactly what the `MONTH(B1)-MONTH(A1)` returns, except it will work over multiple years.

Also, I was considering designing a custom VBA function to achieve the above. If anyone has any suggestions there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use `DATEDIF` but always count from the 1st of the first month you'll get what you need, e.g. if you use `=A1-DAY(A1)+1` that will give you the first of the A1 month, so use that in `DATEDIF` like this

`=DATEDIF(A1-DAY(A1)+1,B1,"m")`

Comment: This works wonderfully! I never would have thought to align each month to the 1st with "DAY". Thanks so much, @barry houdini!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming B1 contains your end date and A1 contains your start date,

```
=IF(DAY(B1)>=DAY(A1),0,-1)+(YEAR(B1)-YEAR(A1))
*12+MONTH(B1)-MONTH(A1)
```

Comment: I think PMC_93 wants to ignore the day, in which case you probably don't need the IF function at the start, this formula should suffice - `=(YEAR(B1)-YEAR(A1))*12+MONTH(B1)-MONTH(A1)` - that will give the same result as my solution with `DATEDIF`

Comment: Thanks! Barry is right; in my case the day is irrelevant. But this formula works just as well!

Answer (score 1):

> I need exactly what the `MONTH(B1)-MONTH(A1)` returns, except it will work over multiple years.

Ok, well, at the risk of stating the obvious:

```
=MONTH(B1)-MONTH(A1) + 12*(YEAR(B1)-YEAR(A1))
```

Rationale: a year is composed of twelve months.

Comment: Thank you! This formula works well. This is a very simple answer; I am new to Excel and solutions like these sometimes escape me.